# Is it safe to store facebook App secret keys in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

Is it safe to store FB App secret keys in a MySQL database? I'd rather not leave it in the code itself... what options do I have?

Comment: no, I mean developer App Secret codes.

Answer (score 1):

Your database is not any safer than your code. Once someone has access to your code, they usually have access to database, at least if your code can connect to database.

This is really subjective but IMO application credentials (as well as database credentials) should be saved in configuration files that stored outside of web-root and have limited access, but again as soon as your code compromised nothing stops attacker from reading configuration too.

Downside of storing application credentials in database is additional query to data.

Comment: hmm so no real advantage besides convenience to store in mysql over files. :P Access to one should lead to access to the other in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever leave secret phrases or passwords in a database; anyone could potentially access it with enough coding.  I would probably write down those secret phrases on a physical piece of paper, why would you even want it in a database?

Comment: because to use the fb web Apps you MUST supply the keys.